# Matlab, fminunc gets stuck (i.e. doesn't return)

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

I have quite a large program, that essentially solve an optimization problem. I'm using `fminunc` for such purpose. For some reason however when the max amount of iterations is reached and the function is supposed to return it literally get stuck. I've tried to follow some of the suggestions which essentially where use nested function in order to avoid dynamic allocation etc (I was loading from a file  everytime the cost function was called).

But still that doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Is there anything a bit more specific I should be aware of? Like some known issue that maybe I currently don't know.

Thank you.
(Let me know what kind of detail I can post).

Some more info:

The output is supposed to be an array of 15876 double, RAM is 32 GB. The actual set up is:

```
option = optimoptions(@fminunc,...
        'Display','iter','GradObj','on','MaxIter',10,...
        'ObjectiveLimit',10e-10,'Algorithm','quasi-newton');
```

I set the number of iterations low just to check if maybe it was the case the number of iterations was the issue, but it doesn't seem to be so. The output I'm getting is:

```
Solver stopped prematurely.

fminunc stopped because it exceeded the iteration limit,
options.MaxIterations = 10 (the selected value)
```

But it doesn't return.

Comment: It is very difficult to say without seeing any code or problem statement. That being, this reads like a more general machine learning question, which might be a better fit on [stats.SE], although be sure to read their [FAQ](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting there.

Comment: How big is the output size of the `fmincon` and how much RAM do you have? Are you sure you are not using too much RAM and the comptuer freezes? What do you mean "it does not return when the maximum iteration is reached"? How do you know that happened if it does not return?

Comment: Why would the computer freeze when the function is returning? (I'm updating the question).

Comment: @user8469759 because you have no RAM, but its not the case. What is what you see that it does not return? Maybe its doing other things inside before returning.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I see the message in my post, which is ok of course. But the thing but even if I waited an hour it still doesn't return.

Comment: @user8469759 you have quite a big problem though. My optimization problems (bigger than yours) can take 3 days. But I see what you mean. We can not really help more without access to the entire problem.

Comment: Looks like I have to wait a while before the function actually returns. The only thing I don't understand is actually what it is doing after all the iterations, If I pause the program while it's executing I can see it is still going through computing gradient etc.